# How to rewrite the url for Slim on a Subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slim

i have a Problem using the Router Slim on a Subdomain.
The router itself works, i can call it and it doesn't cause any errors, but Slim just reads the "/" Route.

---

the Folders

> www 
>   --- .htacccess 
>   --- index.php 
>   --- other Stuff
>   --- subdomain
>   --- --- .htaccess
>   --- --- index.php 
>   --- --- other Stuff

---

in www/.htaccess:

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*.subdomain.example.de.*
>   RewriteRule ^ index.php

---

in subdomain/.htaccess:

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

---

in subdomain/index.php :

> require 'vendor/autoload'
>   $app = new Slim\Slim();
>   
>   $app->get('/', function () {
>   echo 'nothing';
>   });
>   
>   $app->get('/foo', function() {
>   echo 'bar';
>   });
>   
>   $app->run();

---

So, when i open www.subdomain.example.com/foo i get 'nothing'. 
I think the Problem is the rewriting, but i dont know how to fix it.

Thanks for any help. 
josch

Answer (score 2):

I got this solved with the following in `subdomain/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On <br>
RewriteBase /dev-project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: What is dev-project? Directory in sub domain?